# Refering to Object from String

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following piece of code which works perfectly.

However, my list of items below is going to grow to become tens of objects and I want to know if it is possible to remove the switch clause and have something smaller and fewer lines of code.

the 'type' argument is the type of the array, viewport, container, gridpanel, etc. and the 'component' argument is the object itself which goes in the array.

```
viewport: {},
container: {},
gridpanel: {},
panel: {},
treepanel: {},
window: {},
button: {},

add: function (component, type) {

    switch (component.getType() != undefined ? component.getType() : type) {
        case 'container':
            this.container[component.getId()] = component;
            break;
        case 'gridpanel':
            this.gridpanel[component.getId()] = component;
            break;
        case 'panel':
            this.panel[component.getId()] = component;
            break;
        case 'treepanel':
            this.treepanel[component.getId()] = component;
            break;
        case 'viewport':
            this.viewport[component.getId()] = component;
            break;
        case 'window':
            this.window[component.getId()] = component;
            break;
        case 'button':
            this.button[component.getId()] = component;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
},
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) to refer to the component type:

```
add: function(component, type) {
    var componentType = component.getType() || type;
    this[componentType][component.getId()] = component;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Frédéric Hamidi's answer, you may want to restrict the amount of types to be referenced :

```
add: function(component, type) {
    var componentType = component.getType() || type;
    if (Ext.Array.indexOf([
        'container', 'gridpanel', 'panel', 'treepanel', 
        'viewport', 'window', 'button'
    ], componentType) !== -1) {
        this[componentType][component.getId()] = component;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `switch` allows to choose which types you want to add into the array. `indexOf` does a similar job by checking if the component is allowed to be added.